# Pandas apply() with condition on last notnull value and its index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a problem with a code I'm working on right now, so basically what I have is a dataframe with a column filled with numbers in the form  pd.Dataframe([2,2,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,2]) for example. So what I want as an output is this [2,2,2,0,0,0,0,10,0,4] (like a memory effect).

So I'm thinking if there is a way of doing something like this:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x * (index(x) - index( lastnotnull(x) ) ) if x!=0 else 0, axis=1)
```

Any idea would do, but preferably something optimised.

lastnotnull is not really a function, its just a way of explaining what I'm thinking of. So basically what I want is that in each row, it checks if its null, if it is then 0, else it multiplies it by (the number of previous null values +1), so in my example, the fourth 2 becomes 2*(7 - "2") = 10 with 7 the index of the 2 that became 10 and the "2" is the index of the third 2 in the list which is the last not null value of the list.

Comment: Your problem statement is a bit cryptic. Could you better clarify it? I have no idea what is a memory effect in your framework and what you would like to achieve.

For instance, what is the purpose of the "lastnotnull(x)" function?

Comment: lastnotnull is not really a function, its just a way of explaining what I'm thinking of. So basically what I want is that in each row, it checks if its null, if it is then 0, else it multiplies it by (the number of previous null values +1), so in my example, the fourth 2 becomes 2*(7 - "2") = 10 with 7 the index of the 2 that became 10 and  the "2" is the index of the third 2 in the list which is the last not null value of the list. I hope I clarified well.

Answer (score 0):

You included in your post an example how to compute the expected
value: (`2 * (7 - 2) = 10`). It indicates that a more precise formula,
for values *!= 0*, is rather:

```
x * (index(x) - index(previousNonZero(x)))
```

Note the following difference:

- *lastnotnull* (as you wrote) means last **non-null** value in the
  current column, regardless of what is the current element.
  If this column contains no *NaN*, this is the element from the **last**
  row.
- *previousNonZero* (a more precise formula) means that you are
  looking **upwards** from the current element, for an element
  which is *!= 0*. You didn't specify what to do with the **first** row,
  for which there is no *previous* row, so I assumed that the index in
  this case will be *0* (just the same as for the first row).

To have some column name, other than default *0*, I created the source
DataFrame as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2]})
```

so that the column is named *x*.

To find the previous non-zero element (and its index) easily,
let's create an auxiliary DataFrame:

```
wrk = df[df.x != 0]
```

And to generate the expected result, run:

```
result = np.where(df.x != 0, df.x * (wrk.index - wrk.index.to_series()
    .shift(fill_value=0)), 0).astype(int)
```

Details:

- `df.x != 0` - the *condition* parameter to *np.where*,
- `wrk.index.to_series().shift(fill_value=0)` - the index of the
  previous non-zero element in *x* column (with the initial *NaN* replaced
  with *0*),
- `df.x * (wrk.index - ...)` - the formula for *x != 0* case,
- `0` - the formula for *x == 0* case.
- `astype(int)` - convert the result to *int* (otherwise it would be *float*).

The result is:

```
array([ 0,  2,  2,  0,  0,  0,  0, 10,  0,  4])
```

Note that the first element is different from your expected result,
but this is the result of the formula used.

To support my view, let's analyze the case of the first row:

- `x` == 2,
- `index(x)` == 0,
- `index(previousNonZero(x))` == 0,
- `(index(x) - index(previousNonZero(x)))` == 0,
- the final result == 0.

An alternative: Change *fill_value* to *-1* (the index of the "hypothetically"
previous row (if it existed)) and the result will be just as you want.

## Edit

The above code can be reworked into a function, operating on any column
of the source DataFrame:

```
def proc(col):
    wrk = col[col != 0]
    return (col * (wrk.index - wrk.index.to_series()\
        .shift(fill_value=-1))).fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```

In this function still a temporary *Series* (*wrk*) is created, but
after exit from this function it is garbage-collected, so don't worry
about this detail.

Now you can call it:

```
result = proc(df.x)
```

getting (this time a *Series*):

```
0     2
1     2
2     2
3     0
4     0
5     0
6     0
7    10
8     0
9     4
dtype: int64
```

The left column is the index and the right - values (previously in an array).

If you want, change the name of this function to any other of your choice
(I had no better idea).

Comment: Thank you so much, that was exactly what i was looking for, quick question though, I want to implement this as a function that takes a pd.Series type and returns a pd.Series type that would later be updated to a column, is there a way of maybe doing the same function but not go through creating a dataframe and changing the result from ndarray to series? and is it pretty much the same complexity wise ?